# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner

Tags: java, maven

As per my project requirement I am upgrading spring-boot version from "2.1.2.RELEASE" to "2.6.6" and spring-security-oauth2 version from "2.3.4.RELEASE" to "2.5.1.RELEASE". While running my application I am facing below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
at com.auth.application.main(application.java:29) ~[clas
```

Based on few suggestions, I have tried "shell:interactive:enabled:false", "management:security:enabled:false" added in my yaml properties file.But still facing same error.

Please let me know any changes i need to do to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your configuration for pom.xml or gradle